# Configure Azure MySQL Database firewall

Tags: mysql, azure

I created an Azure MySQL Database for a school project, but i have issues with the firewall. Indeed, if i want my friends to connect to the database, i have to add manually their ip address to the firewall.
But the real problem is that i'm not sure that my teacher will accept to share his ip address with me, so he'll maybe not be able to evaluate my work.

So i have tried to disable the firewall (I don't need so much security it's just a school project, and the database will be removed after the evaluation), but i have only found solutions for Azure SQL Database that use settings that don't exist (or no longer exist) for Azure MySQL Database. I have also found this solution using the azure CLI:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-manage-firewall-using-cli#:~:text=message%20text%20instead.-,Delete%20a%20firewall%20rule%20on%20Azure%20Database%20for%20MySQL%20Server,of%20the%20existing%20firewall%20rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-manage-firewall-using-cli#:%7E:text=message%20text%20instead.-,Delete%20a%20firewall%20rule%20on%20Azure%20Database%20for%20MySQL%20Server,of%20the%20existing%20firewall%20rule)

but the commands don't find my server, and if i execute this command:

```
az mysql server list --resource-group myresourcegroup
```

my resource group is found, but it returns an empty list, despite my server really appears in Azure GUI in this resource group

Can you help me to disable this firewall please.

Answer (score 0):

The firewall rules I see in my database instance allow me to create a `0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255` IP range to allow all the hosts.
Obviously, this is not at all secure, but should 'disable' the firewall.
[image]
If you need to do it in CLI then the command would be:
`az mysql server firewall-rule create --resource-group <rg-name> --server-name <server-name> --name DisableFirewall --start-ip-address 0.0.0.0 --end-ip-address 255.255.255.255`

Maybe the teacher doesn't need to actually connect to the database? However, if he has access to the subscription and resource group then he will add his IP for the time he will review your solution if needed.